# Why are the pans mostly black?

Tags: pan, frying-pan

Most pans are black (arbitrary example: https://www.hood.de/i/pfanne-20-cm-81718656.htm ). What advantage does a black pan have as opposed to other pans? Why are there fewer gray pans, aluminium pans or white pans? Why?

Comment: I imagine it has to do with what the pans are made of. Iron/steel: grey-black, stainless steel: shiny silvery, aluminum: less shiny silvery, copper: reddish.

Comment: Same as why car tires are black because it gets dirty easily but you don't want to keep cleaning them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teflon* is black therefore all Teflon pans are black.

Other things are other colours, aluminium, copper, steel, so the outside may vary, but if it's Teflon-coated… it's gonna be black inside.

*Other non-stick coatings are available;)
Ceramic can be white, there's a stone/copper one which is brown/orange or grey speckled, anodised aluminium is dark grey.

Comment: "Teflon" [(Polyetrafluoroethylene)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene#Properties) is white, not black.

Comment: @brhans - Teflon pans don't use 'raw' PTFE, it's some kind of laminate structure… which is black - https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80407/colour-of-polytetrafluorethylene